# Empty charts added by ggplotly when using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, ggplotly

Is there any way to remove the empty charts that are added to the last row when using facet_wrap with ggplotly?

I'm using facet_wrap to generate a plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
g=ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~hp)
print(g)
```

That gives this figure:

[image: ggplot version]

If I try to use ggplotly, extra empty charts are added to the last row.

```
gg = ggplotly(g)
print(gg)
```

[image: ggplotly version]
Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the github version of both ggplot2 and plotly solves the issue.

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")

library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

g=ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~hp)
print(g)

gg = ggplotly(g)
print(gg)
```

Comment: @Nova I just tried this again, and the first time it didn't work, but when I restarted RStudio it did work